# react router v5 privateroute goes to login after logging in and refreshing page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

i'm trying to implement **privateroute** with react router, there is a problem when i login for the first time it goes to the specific page that i want but when i **refresh** the page it goes to login page **even when it's logged in**.

my router code:

```
export default function PsyaRouter() {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  return (
    <Router>
      <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={4} hideIconVariant={false}>
        <Header>
          <CustomSnackbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login">
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/enterPhone">
              <EnterPhone />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/enterCode">
              <EnterCode />
            </Route>
            <PrivateRoute path="/assessment/create">
              <AssessmentForm />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute path="/assessment">
              <Assessment />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <Route path="/users">
              <Users />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/groups">
              <Groups />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/not-found">
              <NotFound />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/not-found" />
          </Switch>
        </Header>
      </SnackbarProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

this is my **privateroute** implementation:

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  // const { last_role_type: userType } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("router auth obj: ", auth);
  }, []); //auth

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return auth.isLoggedIn ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/enterPhone",
              state: { from: props.location },
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page, react remount the whole application which then reset all of your state. To fix this, either using localStorage or sessionStorage to persist your authentication data and then get them for validation in your private route component.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that when you refresh your browser, all of your state and props are cleared to their initial values, the same way as if you typed the address path and hit return.

So, although it's not implied by the code you supplied, it's obvious that your state/prop value `auth.isLoggedIn` is cleared, so probably `false`.